# Can Google Cloud Vision API be trained using your image data?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, google-cloud-vision, watson

IBM Watson has a capability where you can train the classifiers on Watson using your images but I am unable to find a similar capability on Google Cloud Vision API? What I want is that I upload 10-15 classes of images and on the bases of upload images classify any images loaded after that. IBM Bluemix (Watson) has this capability but their pricing is significantly higher than Google. I am open to other services as well, if prices ares below Google's

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know Google Cloud Vision API cannot be trained with your custom data. However, there is a service called [**vize.ai**](https://vize.ai), where you can define your custom classes and upload the images, the training is for free and the prices for API usage are below Google's and IBM's.

Disclaimer: I'm vize.it co-founder

Edit: Link changed

Comment: hi, i tried signing up for the free account ( for an open source project ) but there is an error!

Answer (score 1):

You can train your own models using [Cloud AutoML Vision.](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/train) There are 2 different ways to do this:

1. Cloud-hosted models.
2. Edge exportable models.

Answer (score 0):

With some work you can train a model for free using TensorFlow - see the [model training](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#model-training) section.

However, they have released an [already trained model](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html#image-recognition), so if you're lucky and what you want to classify already overlaps with their model, then no training is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Azure has started this now, google for "azure custom vision" this is still a preview service but with good accuracy at least for our workload which is preschool children images.