# Google Vision Logo Detection API supported logos

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

Does anyone have list of all supported logos by Google Vision API Logo Detection. In the documentation it just mentions that it supports over 0.1 million logos. Does anyone have any further information on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - No, this data is not published.

> "Logo Detection detects popular product logos within an image."

If you need this information because you want to know if the specific logo you are looking for is exist if it's not popular probably not.

You can try tou use [AutoML](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs) and this question maybe relevant [Can Google Cloud Vision API be trained using your image data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136543/can-google-cloud-vision-api-be-trained-using-your-image-data)